# subscript out of range when increasing array size

Tags: vba, range, out

Im creating a userform that gets as many as inputs as possible in an array. every time a new value is entered the array is made bigger
When getting to the second input I get subscript out of range

```
Sub getFlow()


Do
    thisFlow = UserForm4.TextBox1.Value
    If Val(thisFlow) >= 0 Then

        If isInitiated = True Then
            ReDim Preserve flows(1 To UBound(flows) + 1)
        Else
            ReDim flows(1)
            isInitiated = True
            check = True
        End If

            flows(UBound(flows)) = thisFlow
            UserForm4.TextBox1 = ""
                With UserForm4.TextBox1
                .SetFocus
                .SelStart = 0
                .SelLength = Len(.Text)
                End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Value should be equal or greater than zero!"
    End If

Exit Do
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant specify the lower bound when you `ReDim` - You only need to specify the new upper bound.

```
ReDim Preserve flows(UBound(flows) + 1)
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).